# Запуск tomcat из пользователя с паролем

Tags: java, tomcat

Я пытаюсь запустить сервер но получаю такую ошибку

```
Error running WebApp: Cannot run program "/Library/apache-tomcat-
8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/Library/apache-tomcat-
8.5.15/bin"): error=13, Permission denied
```

Система MAC OS если что.
Если я все правильно понял то в папке с tomcat должны произойти какие-то изменения, но поскольку такие действия под паролем то вот и ошибка. Поправьте меня пожалуйста если я не прав.

А как мне установить этот пароль что-бы IntelliJ IDEA сама его вводила?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед запуском .sh, было установлено разрешение на запуск?

```
сd ~/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin
sudo chmod +x ./*.sh
```

Для ознакомления с работой Tomcat на MacOS посмотрите например 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/196136/.

Для конфигурации в Tomcat роли пользователя и пароля доступа обратитесь к файлу

```
~/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

Обращаю внимание, что для работы с Tomcat в IntelliJ IDEA необходима Ultimate версия. Обратите внимание на даную инструкцию http://devcolibri.com/4249.

Comment: На самом деле надо было просто скачивать для мака: `tar.gz (pgp, md5, sha1)` со второй строчки, а не 
`zip (pgp, md5, sha1)` версию с первой тогда все само заработало.